# Split Excel worksheet using Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, numpy, dataframe

I have excel files (hundreds of them) that look like this (sensor output):

```
Column1          Column2    Column3

Serial Number:
10004
Ref. Temp:
25C
Ref. Pressure:
1KPa
Time              Temp.     Pres.
1                 21        1
2                 22        1.1
3                 23        1.2
.                 .         .
.                 .         .
.                 .         .
```

I want to split this into two parts, the information section (top part) and data section (the rest), something like this:

Information section

```
Column1          Column2    Column3

Serial Number:
10004
Ref. Temp:
25C
Ref. Pressure:
1KPa
```

Data section:

```
Column1      Column2    Column3
Time          Temp.     Pres.
1              21       1
2              22       1.1
3              23       1.2
.              .            .
.              .            .
.              .            .
```

if it converts to data frame I don't want the first row and column become header and index of the data frame. I am using python 2.7 and numpy.

Answer (score 1):

- Make two copies of the worksheet.
- In copy A, start a loop, going on the first column looking for the word `Time`. Once it finds it, let it delete anything before it.
- Remember the row in a variable.
- In copy B, delete anything after the remembered row to row number `2^20`.

Comment: I have hundreds of files with several sheets like this. I want to do it automatically. I wonder how I can do it on the fly without doing manually or creating additional files.

Comment: @Bob - there is nothing manual in the solution that I have offered - these are the automatization steps.